# Safe to remove all OWIN packages from MVC5 project with Simple Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I'd like to clean up the project I'm working on. We are using Simple Membership and have no intention of supporting authentication using Twitter, Google, etc. I don't know that much about OWIN but I see quite a few NuGet packages installed by default.

Is it safe to uninstall all of the OWIN packages?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also just had to do this. One of our team had created the MVC 5 website, which included all the OWIN stuff. We're using Membership and so after doing a little digging into the differences (and honestly looking like it would NOT be easy), I just decided to dive head first. Here's what I did:

1. Deleted Startup.cs (this will give an error that's fixed by the next step)
2. Add the following key & value to appSettings in your config:
   `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>`

Comment: @DenverDev, I will refer to your answer at some point. For now I just left things as they were. I commented out relevant code in AuthConfig.cs (I believe) and that got me to where I wanted to be for the time being. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I also had to remove <modules><remove name="FormsAuthentication" /></modules> from my web config.

Comment: This became a problem for me once I published my project to production. I didn't have any trouble during development. Once I published to production I got this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068075/owin-startup-class-missing

Answer (score 24):

You can safely delete all Owin packages and you don't have add `owin:AutomaticAppStartup` key with `false` value.

Just make sure you delete all owin dlls from your bin folders after removing owin packages. They are not cleaned from your bin folder by Visual Studio and somehow they get executed automatically. See my answer in this question:

[c# - OWIN Startup Class Missing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24678109/531524)

Comment: Removing the DLLs from the bin folder was the key for me.

Comment: We need a "clear bin and obj folders" option through Visual Studio because Clean solution is not enough.

Comment: This helped me too, after all these years. Glad I found this answer. Just removing the references, was not enough. I had to delete the dll's from the bin-folder as well.