# ASP.NET Web Api - Startup.cs doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET Web Api solution which doesn't contain a Startup.cs class. I presume this is because the solution wasn't created as an MVC solution.

All the code for the startup is defined in the Global.asax.cs file as you can see below

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

However, now I want to have support for OAuth and all the documentation that I've found is based on a Startup.cs with the following class

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to just add this new class in my solution and the solution will continue working?

Will this have any conflicts with the Global.asax.cs class?

**EDIT**: After I added the Startup.cs class, I can't hit the break point I added into it...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyGame.Startup))]

namespace MyGame
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: make sure you have added `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AuthorizationServer.Startup))]` this above the startup class

Comment: I added it but still doesn't hit the breakpoint when I run the application.

Comment: @user3587624 i have the same problem - did you solve it?

Comment: My issue went gone when I added a reference to Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb in my solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OWIN Startup Class Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068075/owin-startup-class-missing)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Startup.cs is a part of the OWIN authorization package.  If the package isn't added through NuGet, I can't guarantee it would work.  However, judging by this answer, it might work anyway depending on your environment.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24678109/6442626

Short answer: If you installed **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth** from NuGet, that should be good.  Otherwise, you need to install it.

Update:
In order to get MVC to call the Configuration method in startup, you also need to install the **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb** package from NuGet.  There is nothing special you need to change with web.config, IIS will automagically detect the Owin host and load it for you.

Comment: Actually, I added the Startup.cs and the Startup.Auth.cs and it is not breaking in the ConfigurAuth(app) line at all. I added the assemble ([assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyGames.Startup))]) above the namespace... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the package from NuGet?

Comment: I did. I have installed this: <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" /> but also many others like Jwt, Active Directory, etc...

Comment: Do you have 
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
under <appSettings>
in web.config?

Comment: Actually I did that too (found that on another question) but it didn't work either. What actually surprises me is that I need to do all of that on my solution but on a brand new solution neither the [assembly] tag or the key exist in the solution and the Startup works just fine...

Comment: Do you have any OWIN settings under the <runtime> tag in web.config?

Comment: I have one for Microsoft.Owin, another for Microsoft.Owin.Security, other for Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth etc... but nothing for just Owin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139311/discussion-between-tyler-stahlhuth-and-user3587624).

Comment: Just to add here that the issue went gone after adding a reference to Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Comment: Thanks, couldn't figure out why Startup.cs wasn't being called until adding Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package

Answer (score 53):

If you have installed the Owin packages, you can simple create the start up class with:

[image]

Comment: This is correct answer for VS 2015 - It will generate all the necessary code for you.

Comment: make sure you have Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget pkg installed. otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 5):

My Startup.cs would not run until I removed this line on Web.config (in root folder)

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Spent all day trying to work this out and this was the answer.

Comment: This was it for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. first you need to remove the following line from your `web.config`.

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

Only then it will call the the method it `startup.cs`.

Comment: This looks like a bit of a non-answer on an old question.

Comment: @Jason the actual code was hidden because of missing formatting.