# How to use application insights in .net standard library?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, .net-standard, class-library

I have used application insights in web api. It works well. Currently, our controller need call a class library (referred by nuget package). I need to use application insight in class library. There is no exception but nothing logged in Application insights. I write the code as following. Our TelemetryConfiguration have initialized in controller already.

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
var customEvent = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.EventTelemetry
{
    Name = "helloworld",
};
// customEvent.Metrics.Add({ "latency", 42});
telemetryClient.TrackEvent(customEvent);
```

What should I do to make the application insights work?

Comment: "it doesn't work in the library" doesn't explain what's actually happening. Does it throw an exception? Does nothing get logged to AppInsights? Please edit that information into your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the following steps are enough to log to App Insights:

1- In your WebApi startup class and your library project add App Insights assembly thru nuget.

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
```

2- Register App Insights in your startup class:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
```

3- Setup your instrumentation key in appsettings.json:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
  "InstrumentationKey": "<Your instrumentation key here>"
}
```

4- In any class you need, inject a TelemetryClient and use it.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

namespace MyNamesPace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public MyClass(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient= telemetryClient;
        }

        public myClassMethod()
        {
            // Use your _telemetryClient instance
            _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Your Telemetry Event");
        }
    }
}
```

4- In your controller inject your class

```
namespace MyApiNamesPace
{
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMyClass _myClass;

        public MyClass(IMyClass myClass)
        {
            _myClass = myClass;
        }

        public IActionResult myAction()
        {
            _myClass.MyClassMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

5- Don't forget to register your class in your DI container, in startup class:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

Happy programming!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. step 1, step 2 have already done. I think my code in class above is almost same as you write in step 3. But nothing get logged to AppInsights. Since my class is another repo, I referred by nuget package. I don't know whether if affect the behavior.

Comment: Have you setup your key in appsettings.json ?

Comment: In controller, I have set it. But in the repo of my class library, I do not set it.

Comment: I've edited my post to explain how to set it up, second point will use this entry in your  settings file.

Comment: Note that you need to inject the Telemetry in the using class to use the instance and configuration registered in your api project. If you instantiate a new telemetry in your class instead of injecting it, settings are going to get lost.

Comment: Yes, I think this might be where the problem lies. How can I inject the Telemetry in using class? In my api project, I use the interface provided by class library. Pass it my parameter when initial the class?

Comment: No need, keep injecting your class in the container in normal way, let me edit the post.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Since I am not familiar in addscoped, so this may cost a  bit time for me to try this.

Comment: One more thing, since in our repo of webapi, there is no startup.cs, where should I put it?

Comment: What kind of project are you using for your webapi

Comment: Maybe it is a common thing that webapi without startup.cs ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076150/asp-net-web-api-startup-cs-doesnt-exist

Comment: Anyway, thank you, I know the direction to solve the problem

Comment: You may be using Dotnet framework version and not dotnet core version, in this case, is harder to set up because framework version do not have an IOC container out of the box, you will need to use a third party component, on the other hand, with dotnet core IOC container is a first class citizen.